# Change the 'Frame' Label in Plotly Animation

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

*TLDR: I want to label the frame slider with the three letter abbreviation instead of the number for each month.*

I created a bar chart showing average snow depth each month over a 40 year period. I'm pulling my data from NOAA and then grouping by year and month using lubridate. Here is the code:

```
  snow_depth <- govy_data$snwd %>%
     replace_na(list(snwd = 0)) %>%
     mutate(month_char = month(date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>%
     group_by(year = year(date), month = month(date), month_char) %>%
     summarise(avg_depth = mean(snwd))
```

The mutate function creates a column (month_char) in the data frame holding the three letter abbreviation for each month. The class for this column is an ordered factor.

The code below shows how I'm creating the chart/animation:

```
snow_plot <- snow_depth %>% plot_ly(
    x = ~year, 
    y = ~avg_depth, 
    color = ~avg_temp, 
    frame = ~month,
    text = ~paste('<i>Month</i>: ', month_char,
                  '<br><b>Avg. Depth</b>: ', avg_depth, 
                  '<br><b>Avg. Temp</b>: ', avg_temp),
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    type = 'bar'
  )

snow_plot
```

This code generates a plot that animates well and looks like this:

[image: snow chart]

What I'd like to do is change the labels on the slider so instead of numbers, it shows the three letter month abbreviation. I've tried switching the frame to ~month_char which is the ordered factor of three letter month abbreviations. What I end up with, isn't right at all:

[image: snow chart, bad]

The data frame looks like:

[image: snow-depth-df]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fear, with the [current implementation](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/957#issuecomment-488596592) of animation sliders in R's plotly API the desired behaviour can't be realized. This is due to the fact, that no custom animation steps are allowed (this includes the labels). Please see (and support) my [GitHub FR](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1719) for further information.

This is the best I was currently able to come up with:

```
library(plotly)

DF <- data.frame(
  year = rep(seq(1980L, 2020L), each = 12), 
  month = rep(1:12, 41), 
  month_char = rep(factor(month.abb), 41),
  avg_depth = runif(492)
)

fig <- DF %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~year, 
    y = ~avg_depth,
    frame = ~paste0(sprintf("%02d", month), " - ", month_char),
    type = 'bar'
  ) %>%
  animation_slider(
    currentvalue = list(prefix = "Month: ")
  )

fig
```

*(Edit from OP) Here's the resulting graph using the above code*:

[image: Snow Plot With Month Labels]

Comment: This works! Thank you! I've edited your post to show the results from your code. How can I support your FR on GitHub? I'm new to R and GitHub

Comment: You can just leave a thumbs up emoji under the post - they can be used to filter for the most wanted features.

Comment: Thanks, @ismirsehregal!  This was really helpful.