# How can I remove (animation) frame titles in Plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm using R-plotly to produce a scatterplot and have been trying to remove the animation frame title (e.g. "am:0" in the example below).
I can remove the legends for axis and colour; how can I remove animation frame title, or alternatively set it to some custom text e.g. "Foreign"

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- mtcars  %>% mutate(cyl = as_factor(cyl))

scatter_plot <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~cyl, frame = ~am) %>%  
layout(xaxis = list(title = " "), yaxis = list(title = " "), legend=list(title= list(text = " ")))

scatter_plot
```

[image: Plotly scatter in R with axis titles removed]

I can't find any information on removing the frame title.
In addition, the legend title is only removed when cyl is a factor.

Comment: Here is another reference: https://plotly.com/r/animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Change the 'Frame' Label in Plotly Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152879/change-the-frame-label-in-plotly-animation) @ismirsehregal's answer:

**First approach:**

Add this to your code: `animation_slider(currentvalue = list(prefix = ""))`. This will remove `am:`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- mtcars  %>% mutate(cyl = as_factor(cyl))

scatter_plot <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~cyl, frame = ~am) %>%  
  layout(xaxis = list(title = " "), 
         yaxis = list(title = " "), 
         legend=list(title= list(text = " "))) %>% 
  animation_slider(currentvalue = list(prefix = "")) 

scatter_plot
```

[image]

**Second approach:**

If we want to remove also 0 and 1, then we can set `animation_slider(currentvalue = list(visible = FALSE))`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- mtcars  %>% mutate(cyl = as_factor(cyl))

scatter_plot <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~cyl, frame = ~am) %>%  
  layout(xaxis = list(title = " "), 
         yaxis = list(title = " "), 
         legend=list(title= list(text = " "))) %>% 
  animation_slider(currentvalue = list(visible = FALSE))

scatter_plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely. NB - these solutions cause plotly to give an error if frame variable has only one value.